# Create instance using Activator

Tags: c#, reflection

I got some troubles with Activator.CreateInstance. It throws "Constructor on type not found" exception.

Here is the method where error occurs:

```
private static void InitializeInternalProperty(Calculation calculation, Type type, IDataProvider dataProvider, params string[] precedants)
{
    PropertiesCollection precedantsCollection = new PropertiesCollection(); //Properties collection implements IKeyedCollection
    foreach (string precedant in precedants)
    {
        precedantsCollection.Add(calculation.properties[precedant]);
    }
    calculation.properties.Add((Property)Activator.CreateInstance(type, dataProvider, precedantsCollection));
}
```

Here is the constructor, i am trying to use:

```
internal CountryRiskPremium(IDataProvider dataProvider, PropertiesCollection precedants)
{
    Name = Names.CountryRiskPremium;
    InitLinks(precedants);
    _dataProvider = dataProvider;
}
```

I also tried:

```
object[] arguments = new object[2];
arguments[0] = dataProvider;
arguments[1] = precedantsCollection;
calculation.properties.Add((Property)Activator.CreateInstance(type, arguments));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Activator` only works with public constructors, with the simple overload of `CreateInstance` that you are using. For using `private`/`protected`/`internal` constructors, you need to use another overload. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance.

Comment: The overload that is mentioned only works with public constructors

Comment: That would be a much better way of expressing it - yes